# extjs localization - text curroption

Tags: extjs

When I use extjs localization, I get the text curropted like it was encoded right. I have no clue where to start digging. it is not a font issue, it seems like the machanism that brings do the translations in extjs failed with the encoding or the server that serve the translation file brings it with bad encoding.
don't know.
anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it. make sure you have this in the HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

reference:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/localization